# The use of \date{} doesn't remove the date

Tags: date

In fact, I want to remove the date. I saw that I have to use \date{}, but in my case nothing happens and the date is still there. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,stdletter,orderfromtodate,sigleft]{newlfm}
\usepackage{blindtext, xfrac}
\setlength\parindent{1cm}
\newlfmP{dateskipbefore=50pt}
\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt}
\newlfmP{sigskipbefore=50pt}
\newlfmP{Headlinewd=0pt,Footlinewd=0pt}
\date{}
 \usepackage{etoolbox} \makeatletter \patchcmd{\@zfancyhead}{\fancy@reset} 
 {\f@nch@reset}{}{} \patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyolh}{\f@nch@olh}{}{} 
 \patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyolh}{\f@nch@olh}{}{} \patchcmd{\@set@em@up} 
 {\f@ncyorh}{\f@nch@orh}{}{} \makeatother

 \begin{document}
 \begin{newlfm}
 \blindtext
 \Blindtext

 \end{newlfm}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: I think you have to use the `dateno` option to remove the date in `newlfm`.

Comment: The date is still there

Comment: Use: `\documentclass[12pt,stdletter,orderfromtodate,sigleft,dateno]{newlfm}` as suggested by Nicola Talbot and the date won't appear.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `newlfm` class, the date visibility is set using the `dateno` (no date) and `dateyes` (show date) options. (As far as I can tell, this is just for letters, not for the memo, fax or press release options.) You can supply `dateno` as a class option:

```
\documentclass[12pt,stdletter,orderfromtodate,sigleft,dateno]{newlfm}
```

or using `\newlfmP`:

```
\newlfmP{dateno}
```

The date is set using `\dateset` (not `\date`).